# Unable to deploy app on google app engine using jetty:"HTTP ERROR 404 Pblm accessing /.Reason: not found"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets, jetty

Ive bee trying to set up a sample 'todo' google app engine example that uses Java, using an article I found [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html) .

However, when I try to run the application locally, and check the localhost:8888 address I get the following error:

```
HTTP ERROR: 404

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    NOT_FOUND
Powered by Jetty://
```

I've double checked my appengine-web.xml and  the web.xml. But cant seem to figure out where Im going wrong.

Links:  [Appengine-web.xml](https://gist.github.com/KodeSeeker/54d0659c9113ffea916b).
 [web.xml](https://gist.github.com/KodeSeeker/5147762)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your appengine-web.xml and web.xml seem correct, but in your web.xml there is:

```
<servlet-class>com.test.todo.dao..ServletRemoveTodo</servlet-class>
```

Did you realise these 2 dots? I think that's the problem. The server can't find the servlet and throws NOT FOUND error.

It should be:

```
<servlet-class>com.test.todo.dao.ServletRemoveTodo</servlet-class>
```